# SceneKit - Audio causes cxa_throw with a lag the first time I play a sound

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, audio, scenekit

I play back a sound like this ( this is inside a SCNNode subclass ):

```
    let audioSource = SCNAudioSource(named: "coin.wav")
    let audioPlayer = SCNAudioPlayer(source: audioSource)
    self.addAudioPlayer(audioPlayer)
```

The first time this is called, I get a severe lag and an expection is thrown.
I notice the lag, when I disable the All_Expection_Breakpoint.

What can I do against this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The C++ exception comes from AVAudioEngine that is used by the SceneKit audio layer. The AVAudio* framework uses C++ exceptions internally so if you have a breakpoint set in Xcode to break when C++ exceptions are thrown Xcode will break a lot in the AVAudio* code (mostly at init times). You can safely ignore these as they are caught by the framework before they reach your code anyway.

If you don't want the lag you can instantiate your audio source and load it at startup time:
     let audioSource = SCNAudioSource(named: "coin.wav")
     audioSource.load()

And then add the player when you need it later:
    let audioPlayer = SCNAudioPlayer(source: audioSource)
    self.addAudioPlayer(audioPlayer)

By the way, players are cached and recycled so you don't have to worry too much about memory being used for nothing.

Note also that the SCNAction uses exactly the same API than you do, so if you create an action with a sound that hasn't previously been loaded in memory with .load() you will also get a lag.

Hope this helps,

S.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this, but using the load-function also doesn't help. What prevents the lag from happening is playing a silent sound (any sound) before really using the audio engine. I'm pretty sure this is a bug inside SceneKit's Audio engine that just will make anything lag the first time any sound is played. Have you noticed something similar?

Comment: Could you file a radar about this lag thing? This is clearly a bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is really only for atmospheric, ambient and background environment sorts of sounds, to be looped and moved with a character or attached to the position of a waterfall or something like that.

It's not a performant, instant sound player for immediate sound effects requiring low latency.

For that you're better off using an SCNAction to play the audio as an Action when needed, or using something like Fmod that's designed for low latency sound playback.

I'm not sure how I know this.

Comment: Thank you! This is correct, but though the initial stutter with the C++ exception that is being thrown is still there.

Comment: AVAudioPlayer has an interesting feature known as "prepareToPlay"

Comment: Would it be terrible to poke around and see if you could provoke this prepareToPlay method?

Comment: But I can not access it from using an action.

Comment: You could incur the load time of the coin.wav file earlier by calling the SCNAudioSource.load() function at a time convenient to you. This will probably achieve the same thing, and remove the need to use Actions to play instant sounds.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Though the lag and the exception still happen.

Comment: And is your sound effect file mono (not stereo) and in the right format? There's a gazillion formats for .wav files. You should hire a professional to compress into .caf format

Comment: It's mono, 16 bit little endian, 44.1 kHz. That should be the perfect format, but still no luck.